# Trying to create a form for a ASP web app

Tags: web-applications, asp-classic, vbscript

I am creating a ASP Web Application and one of the things I need to do is use the data that the user filled out. There is one text field and multiple radio buttons.

I'm new to ASP so I am doing one piece at a time...the text field.

I have

```
<form method="post"  action="/Scripts/checklistForm.asp"> <%-- TODO: Enter variables    into checklistForm.vbs --%>
<table>
<tr> 
  <td class="label">
    FQDN: </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="FQDN" style="width: 250px" />
 </td>
 <td> <input type="radio" name="TestScript" /></td>
 <td class="label">Test Script</td>
</tr>
</table>

<br />
<div id="Button">
<asp:Button ID="cancelButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel" Width="58px" />
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="runButton" UseSubmitBehavior="true" runat="server" Text="Run" Width="58px" />  
</div>
</form>
```

I want to use the two buttons at the bottom.
1) I want the "Run" button to be the submit button. 
2) I want to use the "cancel" button to close the browser window.

I am testing this form just using a simple script
checklistForm.asp is simply a msgbox popup

```
<%
MsgBox("Hello"); 
%>
```

but it simply isn't working.

Go easy on me, I am still new to ASP.

Also, I am editing it in Visual Studio. Is this the best editor for this?
I am a software developer and this is a work project.

Comment: There is no `MsgBox` in classic asp.  This is VBScript.  You need to use javascript alert() box.

Comment: also there is no <asp:Button in classic asp you are mixing asp.net and classic asp

Comment: Bah, I am confusing ASP and ASP.net. Should I be using ASP.net, I would prefer to stick to VBScript.

Comment: On that note, my boss said this was to be an ASP application. Should I move over to ASP.net and learn that real quick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you follow this simple tutorial which will help you understand ASP forms.

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_inputforms.asp